# Pandas dataframes - join on similar timestamps

Tags: python, join, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes,

```
small_df = 
   time_early            
0, 18:19:20.877154
1, 20:34:24.738802
```

and `large_df`, with many more rows

```
   time_late      
0, 11:12:23.879154
1, 11:12:23.879154            
2, 18:19:20.879154
3, 19:01:20.877154
4, 20:34:24.748802
```

I want to join them in such a way that every row in `small_df` is joined to a row in `large_df` that comes immediately after it, so that the desired result looks something like

```
   time_early           time_late 
0, 18:19:20.877154      18:19:20.879154
1, 20:34:24.738802      20:34:24.748802
```

Also, assume that these 2 dataframes may have other columns that I would like to maintain in the final result. How do I achieve this? I know I need some kind of merge, but not exactly sure.

Comment: FYI - it looks like a typo in your second time_early in your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def join_closest_time(df):
    # first of all get values that is greater than time_early for each row
    time_greater = large_df.time_late > df['time_early']
    # subset data to get only the first one , this should be the closest one
    # to time early if time_late columns is sorted in ascending order
    close_date = large_df[time_greater].iloc[0]
    # then concatenate rows from both data frames
    df_final = pd.concat([df , close_date])
    return df_final

small_df.apply(join_closest_time, axis = 1)


Out[116]:
    time_early          time_late
0   18:19:20.877154 18:19:20.879154
1   20:34:24.738802 20:34:24.748802
```

if your `large_df` is not sorted by `time_late` you've to sort it first in ascending order

```
large_df.sort_index(by = 'time_late' , inplace=True)
```

Comment: Trimming is no good, it should know how to take difference of time values. What if one is 5.9s, the other 6.1s? Trimming logic is silly.
Also, I get a lot of duplicates like this. I think the correct solution involves some sort of filling (bfill of ffill) combined with merge, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: so how do you define time  `comes immediately after the early time`

Comment: Whichever from the time_late appears first right after a specific instance of time_early.

Comment: ok I got you point , is your late time sorted in ascending order , like the example?

Answer (score 0):

If there is any `time_late` following a specific `time_early` value, take the first value.  Otherwise, use `None`.

```
small_df['time_late'] = \
    small_df.time_early.apply(lambda time: large_df[large_df.time_late > time].values[0][0]        
                                           if large_df.time_late.gt(time).any() else None)

>>> small_df
        time_early        time_late
0  18:19:20.877154  18:19:20.879154
1  20:34:24.738802  20:34:24.748802
```